# Извлечение из списка значения

Tags: python

Есть список(чуть ниже)
как из него достать значение "amount",которое ровняется 1.83

```
{"accounts":[{"alias":"qw_wallet_rub","fsAlias":"qb_wallet","bankAlias":"QIWI","title":"Qiwi Account","type":{"id":"WALLET","title":"Visa QIWI Wallet"},"hasBalance":true,"balance":{"amount":1.83,"currency":643},"currency":643,"defaultAccount":true},
{"alias":"qw_wallet_kzt","fsAlias":"akb_wallet","bankAlias":"AKB","title":"Qiwi Account","type":{"id":"WALLET","title":"Visa QIWI Wallet"},"hasBalance":true,"balance":{"amount":0.00,"currency":398},"currency":398,"defaultAccount":false},{"alias":"qw_wallet_usd","fsAlias":"qb_wallet","bankAlias":"QIWI","title":"Qiwi Account","type":{"id":"WALLET","title":"Visa QIWI Wallet"},"hasBalance":true,"balance":{"amount":0.00,"currency":840},"currency":840,"defaultAccount":false}]}
```

Comment: 1. Это не список. 2. Такие вопросы здесь появляются по нескольку раз в неделю. Поле для поиска в самом верху страницы.

Comment: Откуда вы берёте этот список? Это текст в файле с расширением .json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не список, а словарь. (Для скобок: `{...}` - словарь,  `[...]` - список).

Сверх того, в нем значения `true` и `false`, которые наносят ошибку, потому что в Питоне они пишутся с прописной начальной буквой: `True`, `False`.

Чтобы исправить это, используйте сначала команды

```
true = True
false = False
```

---

Теперь, пусть `dic` имя вашего словаря:

```
dic = {"accounts":[{"alias":"qw_wallet_rub","fsAlias":"qb_wallet", ...
```

Тогда значение 1.83 получите так:

```
dic["accounts"][0]["balance"]["amount"]
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Постепенно мы получаем, заходя все глубже:

1. Ключ `"accounts"` имеет как значение список:

   ```
   dic["accounts"] есть список [{"alias":"qw_wallet_rub","fsAlias":"qb_wallet", ...
   ```
2. Первой элемент этого списка (т.е. нулевой) есть словарь:

   ```
   dic["accounts"][0] есть словарь {"alias":"qw_wallet_rub","fsAlias":"qb_wallet", ...
   ```
3. В этом словаре находится ключ `"balance"`, которого значение есть словарь:

   ```
   dic["accounts"][0]["balance"] есть словарь {"amount":1.83,"currency":643},"currency":643,"defaultAccount":true}{"alias":"qw_wallet_rub","fsAlias":"qb_wallet",
   ```
4. Но и наконец, в этом словаре находится ваш ключ `"amount"` со значением 1.83:

   ```
    dic["accounts"][0]["balance"]["amount"] есть 1.83
   ```

Comment: Выдает ошибку 
NameError: name 'true' is not defined

Comment: @Bytovskiy, ваш словарь включает в себе ошибку — см. мой модифицированный ответ, как с неё исправиться.

Comment: Очепятка в первой строке.

Comment: @Bytovskiy, коротко говоря, нужно вам применит перед определением словаря исполнить команды `true = True` и `false = False`.

Comment: Это не код на Питоне, это JSON.